# unable to access Magento 2.4.6 backend on a fresh install with sampledata

Tags: backend

I'm unable to access the Magento 2.4.6 backend on a fresh install with sampledata

I get this when I try to open the Magento Backend URL

> Error: Class "Magento\ThemeSampleData\Plugin\View\Page\Config" not
> found in
> /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121?

The frontend is working fine.

any idea how to get this resolved?